# Assign value to subset of numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given the following array:

```py
x = np.zeros((1, 5))
x
# array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

I'd like to be able to create  `array([[0., 3., 1., 0., 8.]])` using something like:

```py
values = [3, 1, 8]
indices = [1, 2, 4]
x.iloc[indices] = values
```

I understand that this doesn't work - but I'm not sure what an idiomatic approach to this sort of thing in numpy would be.

The following *works*, but it doesn't seem like it's a sensible approach using numpy:

```py
values = [3, 1, 8]
indices = [1, 2, 4]
for i, v in zip(indices, values):
    row[i] = v
```

Comment: Beside the point, but `row` is not defined. Looks like it's supposed to be `row = x[0]`.

Comment: Is `y = x.iloc[indices] = values` a typo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just move the indexer to the second position (because you're modifying values in the second dimension):

```
x[:, indices] = values
```

Output:

```
>>> x
array([[0., 3., 1., 0., 8.]])
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the put method from numpy to achieve this:

```
np.put(x, indices, values)
```